# Cache Channel Service - Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

On our single-server dev environment I've enabled the Object Cache and the RemoteSynchronization with default settings.

When I published a taxonomy I can see in the logs stuff like:

```
DEBUG RMICacheChannelConnector - Attempting to look up cache channel service on //localhost:1099/CacheChannelService
DEBUG RMICacheChannelConnector - Successfully set cache channel service
DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 1  memSize = 128
DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 2  memSize = 5339
DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [35:5034] in Region [/com.tridion.broker.Taxonomies.Taxonomy] to Object [35-5034-5034-512-TF1.left>=TF.left AND TF1.right<=TF.right] in Region [/com.tridion.broker.Taxonomies.Taxonomy]
```

But when I unpublish the cache is never updated as I still get cached results, ie. I can still retrieve the taxonomy through my API calls when I expect after unpublishing not to.

I have to restart the service to get changes flushed through.

Having read [Julian's arctile](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/whatisthesdltridionobjectcache.aspx) its almost like my broker isn't receiving any cache invalidations - is this possible? Does an invalidation message show up in the logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to your application, Did you configure your deployer also with Remote Synchronization.? Whenever you publish any new items, deployer(httpupload) need to notify the cache channel service for invalidation so application API knows (CCS) to get the latest content from broker DB.

Comment: God damn it! Great spot Ram. Had to update the cd_storage_conf for the deployer to.

Comment: For those not aware: Tridion's Content Delivery Caching works between JVM instances. So the **Remote** in Remote Synchronization applies whenever you have more than one JVM, even when they are on the same machine. Nowadays you'll almost always want to set RemoteSynchronization to true, since you'll have the Deployer running in a separate process (either as a HTTP upload web app or as a Windows service) from your content-serving web site.